# How would one make a function in javascript so when the button is clicked, another button appears?

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I am trying to make something a puzzle for a school project and for one of the puzzles, it requires me to make almost like an among-us fixing wire game. The most simple way to do that and do to get to get the best result is to use buttons. But how would I make it so when my first button is clicked, the second one appears?

I've tried using inputs, and the text appear.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far and we can help from there.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question is really several in one. Please make an effort and then ask a more specific question about your code.

Comment: Hints: `getElementById()`, `addEventListener()`, `classList.add()`.

Comment: Note that the `puzzle` tag you included reads "DO NOT USE". I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following css for the hidden buttons:

```
#hidden_button{
   display: none;
}
```

Then in javascript set up a listener for when you button is clicked:

```
button.addEventListener("click",show_second_button);
```

The function "show_second_button" will edit the css to show the hidden button:

```
var show_second_button = function(){
     document.getElementById("hidden_button").style.display = "block";
}
```

Setting the display style from "none" to "block" will cause the hidden button to appear.

Comment: We prefer not to provide answers that simply do a person's work for them. Please see both [ask] and [answer], and take the [tour], to get a sense of our expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an `onclick` on the first button.

An quick example :

```
<button id="firstButton" onclick='document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = "block"'>Click me</button>
<button id="hideMe">I'm visible !</button>
```

This would work if you want one button to show an other but for multiple uses I recommand to use functions. And if you want more interaction the best way is to call function in your `onclick`.

```
function showBtn(buttonName){
    //Button Name is the Id of your button
    document.getElementById("buttonName").style.display = "block";
}
```